# Cite without author's name

Tags: bibliographies, citing

The `\cite` command places the author's name and date in the document. If I have already mentioned an author's name, though, I only need the date and maybe a letter:
"Lewis (1998b) claimed that ..."
How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE; you should also tell which packages you are using, as the default behavior of LaTeX for citations is not author-year. Is it natbib, biblatex or another package?

Comment: It's just bibtex. I'm not using any special packages. I've been thinking of switching to natbib, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you happen to use the `natbib` package, `\citeyear{key}` should give you the
year and  `\citeyearpar{key}` the year in parentheses. There is also the complementary command `\citeauthor{key}` to give you the author(s) only. See the beginning of `natbib.sty` for other options.