# Cite a standard, specification or data sheet from a company/institution but without an author

Tags: citing, ieeetran

As an electronic engineer I often cite technical standards, specifications or data sheets. They come usually from a specific company or institution but do not have a specific author. I like to have them in my bibliography using all the required information like title, institution, year, version/revision/edition and type ("whitepaper", "data sheet", "standard" etc.). Unfortunately I failed to come up with a general solution for this. Often I used the `misc` or `manual` type but it often does not include all information.

What would be a suitable way to handle such citations? I need to use the `IEEEtran` class with the `vancover` (or similar) style for my current journal paper, but I also would welcome a general solution using `biblatex` (which I use for my thesis).

Comment: I found the questions [Bibtex entry to cite an article with unknown author?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19093/bibtex-entry-to-cite-an-article-with-unknown-author) and [Cite without author name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18401/cite-without-author-name) which go into a similar direction, but offer no solution to my problem.

Comment: I'd go with `techreport`, but I guess it has almost the same fields of either `misc` or `manual`. `:(`

Comment: JabRef offers the entrytype `standard`, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8817/how-to-cite-omg-specifications

Answer (score 29):

With `biblatex` I use `manual`:

```
@manual{nxp:tja1043,
    organization  = "NXP Semiconductors",
    title         = "High-speed CAN transceiver",
    number        = "TJA1043",
    year          =  2013,
    month         =  4,    
    note          = "Rev. 3"
}

@manual{infineon:TLE4473GV55-2,
    organization  = "Infineon Technologies AG",
    title         = "Dual Low Dropout Voltage Regulator",
    number        = "TLE 4473 GV55-2",
    year          =  2008,
    month         =  10,
    note          = "Rev. 1.2"
}

@manual{freescale:33879A,
    organization  = "Freescale Semiconductor",
    title         = "Configurable Octal Serial Switch
                    with Open Load Detect Current Disable",
    year          =  2012,
    month         =  6,
    number        = "MC33879",
    note          = "Rev. 10.0"
}
```

[image: referenced documents]

Comment: When doing this, the number doesn't appear for me.

Comment: @CharlesClayton: That's probably due to your `bibliographystyle`. Try using `\bibliographystyle{plain}`.

Comment: I had to use `author` instead of `organization` for it to show up.

Answer (score 6):

With JabRef I use `misc` or `standard`. The standards body is normally typed out fully, rather than abbreviated:

[image]

In the building industry sometimes, specifications provide a list of standards.

[image]

Comment: Could you also post the bibtex code for such an entry. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinScharrer You mean the standards or the entries on top? I will check my computer at work and dig it out to-morrow. The standards is just a tabular.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides If you got it somewhere, the BibTeX code would be appreciated :)

Comment: Random question: on what kind of OS did you make the screenshot? It clearly is a TNR variant but it looks so... oddly good.

Answer (score 1):

As commented on a previous answer, the number field would not show up using the `@manual` entry type (with `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` using Texmaker v5.0.4 & MiKTeX v21.7 on Windows 10). A workaround for this, however, is to use the `Address` field for the component number, as this places the component number in the correct position, and with the correct text styling as according to "[IEEE Citation Guidelines](https://ieee-dataport.org/sites/default/files/analysis/27/IEEE%20Citation%20Guidelines.pdf)".

[image: PDF output provided by using the Address field]

**EDIT:** I have just realised that the organisation should be at the start of the citation, this could be solved by entering the name of the organisation into the `Author` field, and then ensuring that it is enclosed within double curly braces (e.g. `author = {{Texas Instruments}}`). This would produce an output identical to the example in the guidelines linked above.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch thank you, I'm glad I could give back something, this whole SE has been an invaluable resource as a university student :)